# Checkboxes disappear when materializecss is applied (using django)

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms, materialize

The code with the css makes the checkboxes disappear for cash.
They have been initialised as boolean variables in the model(using django).

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Payment Method:</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>{{ seller_event_form.cash_payment }}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Without the css, the checkboxes appear. Because of this, none of the data inputted gets stored in the database.

**edit with more info**

I'm trying to unpack a model form here. When I unpack without adding any css, the boolean value in the model gets converted to a checkbox in the html. However, when I add css, the checkbox disappears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This isn't clear enough to receive a good answer and will likely get downvoted, could you clarify what you are trying to do and whats going wrong?

Comment: I added more information. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: What css do you add? In any case, css code wouldn't cause your form not to be submitted properly, least on boolean fields.